# Why does a point mass make a certain angle with a force exerted on it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

In real world, I see that if I hit (physicall speaking exert a force on)a marble or billiard ball properly (I think in its center of mass) it goes in a straight line with the force which means the angle between force and displacement is zero($0$). But in determining work we use $W=Fs\cos{\theta}$. So if we exert a force on a point mass, it should go in a straight line making an angle of $0$ with force. So why does the point mass make an angle of $\theta$ instead of $0$? Can there be a certain angle without another force working on the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ W = F (s \cos \theta) $ applies when $F$ is not the only force acting on the body, and thus the resulting path is at an angle to $F$. Commonly you examine things like blocks sliding on wedges and things rolling on surfaces. In each case, in adddition to the applied force $F$ there is a reaction force $N$, the (vectorial) combination of results in the motion.

- So a single marble without gravity you have in vector form $\boldsymbol{F} = m \boldsymbol{a}$ and because $m$ is a scalar, the vectors $\boldsymbol{F}$ and  $\boldsymbol{a}$ are parallel.
- But a marble rolling down a ramp will have $\boldsymbol{F} + \boldsymbol{N} = m \boldsymbol{a}$ with a value of $\boldsymbol{N}$ such that the acceleration is *only* along the direction of the ramp (lets call the motion direction $\hat{\boldsymbol{e}}$, and the normal direction $\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}$). So if $\boldsymbol{a} = \hat{\boldsymbol{e}} a$ and $\boldsymbol{N} = \hat{\boldsymbol{n}} N$ the solution is $$ \begin{aligned} a & = \frac{1}{m} (\hat{\boldsymbol{e}} \cdot \boldsymbol{F}) = \frac{F \cos\theta}{m} \\ 
  N & = -\hat{\boldsymbol{n}} \cdot \boldsymbol{F} = -F \sin\theta \end{aligned} $$

Comment: That's what I really wanted to know. That if no only one force acts on a body then what would be its path

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are correct. If a force is exerted on the center of mass of an object, the object will always accelerate in the same direction as the applied force unless there is some other constraint (e.g. gravity force, electrostatic force, mechanical force such as the reaction of the train track) on the object. In the presence of some other constraint (force), the work done by the applied force will only equal the component of the applied in the direction of its motion.

If someone can show us an example where this is not the case, please do.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you said about the real life condition was true but not exactly.  Suppose there was a railway wagon on a straight track ( x axis supposing). Now you push it so that the force you give will make an angle β with the track. Now the force component along the track will cause it to move along the track in the direction of the force component.  Now if you will notice the force component perpendicular to the track does not cause any displacement (unless you push so hard as to topple it off the track) and hence the work will be done only by the cosβ component. This is what is conveyed by the cosβ term in the formula. It is not always necessary that the body will go in the direction of force. As we know that the work done is equal to the dot product of force and displacement.
That is why the cosβ term is there.

Comment: I forgot to ask my main question. In your ans the perpendicular  component can't do anything because there is an opposite force working on that train by the track. If that opposite force wasn't present then that would not happen?

Comment: Then i also said that work done is the dot product of force and displacement. if you have read vectors then you would know tgat the dot of two perpendicular vectors is 0.

Answer (score 0):

A point mass cannot make a certain angle when force acts on it. It will have to move in the same direction. For a rigid body, the case makes more sense where we can say that some force acts on the body at some angle.

$ W = Fdcos\theta$ holds true. $\theta$ here is the angle between the force vector applied on the block and the horizontal. The displacement happens because there is a *component* acting along the direction that the block can move.

Comment: Is there a reason why my answer was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

In everyday life, if you throw an object horizontally in the vertical gravity field, its trajectory is not vertical !
If you exert a force on a punctual mass at rest, it will actually accelerate in the direction of the force. But if the point mass already has a speed, axial symmetry no longer exists! This is the reason why the planets do not fall: they are drawn towards the sun but have a non-zero orthoradial velocity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/246078)

Comment: Sorry ! I have completed the answer.